# Solving many instances with pyomo in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pyomo, pyro

I'm using Pyomo library to solve an optimization problem with Gurobi optimizer. I have an academic license for Gurobi, but afaik this should not pose any kind of limitation. I'd like to optimize the model with different parameters in parallel. In other words, I have many instances of the same model but different parameters that could be solved independently.

I've followed the instruction that I found on the documentation page of Pyomo regarding pyro and dispatching ([here](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modeling_extensions/pysp.html?highlight=parallel#solving-sub-problems-in-parallel-and-or-remotely) the reference). Basically, I started the Pyomo name server with `pyomo_ns`, then the dispatch server with `dispatch_srvr`, and finally I have launched four instances of `pyro_mip_server`.

When I launch my python script it works. No errors occur. The problem is that it takes the same amount of time as the serial execution. I've also monitored the activity of all eight cores that my CPU has and only one is constantly at 100% of the load. It's like no concurrent execution is happening at all.

I'm using SolverManager provided by Pyomo library to submit from the Python script different instances of my model. You can find [here](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_models.html#solving-multiple-instances-in-parallel) the guide of how to use it.

I'm on a Linux machine, the latest LTS Ubuntu distro.

Have somebody had such an experience or does someone know what's the problem here? If you need any additional info just let me know :). Thank you!